# File/DLL installed to {sys} does not appear in C:\Windows\system32

Tags: inno-setup, 32bit-64bit

I don't know why, but when I try to copy a file from my install directory to `system32`, it fails to do so although it reads as successfully installing in Inno Setup.   Here is my code:

```
[Files]
; specifies what files will be included in the installation
Source: "{src}\..\elt.properties"; DestDir: "C:\elt"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{src}\..\msvcr120.dll"; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist;
```

I also wanted to include my log output as I thought it was strange that the time was so off for the file, I am writing this around 11 am on July 8 2016

```
[11:49:36.526]   -- File entry --
[11:49:36.528]   Dest filename: C:\Windows\system32\msvcr120.dll
[11:49:36.529]   Time stamp of our file: 2013-10-04 23:58:24.000
[11:49:36.530]   Installing the file.
[11:49:36.566]   Successfully installed the file.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default the `{sys}` (`system32`) [is redirected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) to `{win}\SysWOW64` by the OS for 32-bit applications (like Inno Setup).

If your DLL (or rather the application) is 32-bit, you actually want the redirection. The `SysWOW64` is the `System32` equivalent for Windows 32-bit emulation on Windows 64-bit. See also [Inno Setup install to SysWOW64 in 32Bit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29583694/850848).

---

If you do not want the redirection (because your DLL/application is 64-bit), you can override the redirect using the [`64bit` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection):

```
Source: "..."; DestDir: "{sys}"; Flags: 64bit
```

> **64bit**: Causes the `{sys}` constant to map to the 64-bit System directory when used in the `Source` and `DestDir` parameters, .... This is the default behavior in a [64-bit mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls) install.

---

Or enable [64-bit mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls) install.

```
[Setup]
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64 ia64
```

> In 64-bit mode:
>
> - The System32 path returned by the `{sys}` constant maps to the 64-bit System directory by default when used in the [Dirs], [Files], [InstallDelete], [Run], [UninstallDelete], and [UninstallRun] sections. This is because Setup/Uninstall temporarily disables [WOW64 file system redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) when files/directories are accessed by those sections. Elsewhere, System32 and `{sys}` map to the 32-bit System directory, as is normal in a 32-bit process.