# Inno Setup - Attempting To Move Folders to Group Policy In \system32

Tags: windows-7, inno-setup, group-policy

This is a bit involved for a first post, but I'm sort of at the end of my rope and I figured I'd ask for help at this point.

I'm internal IT(originally just helpdesk but now having to do all kinds of crap) at a local company. The department is very ad hoc. No Tier I-III, network engineers are deployed to other departments such that I can't access them; infrastructure for a lot of things was set up by people who are long gone. Got no one to kick this sort of stuff to.

I've got some 500+ users that are all work-from-home. They're supposed to be connected to a domain GPO, but around 5-10% of them get disconnected and lose access to a number of their applications. Trying to work around the issue by creating an installer that'll change their local GP instead. Just toss an installer at the very non-tech-savvy users, tell 'em to run it, and they're golden.

Unfortunately, from reading around here, I'm seeing that there is no way to write to any Win7 system folders? Is there any way at all around this?

- Have confirmed that the folders will write fine to non-system directories.
- Tried running the installer as admin
- Regarding the GPO issue itself:

  - Can't remove/add users using Powershell for whatever reason(Powershell informs me that the user's computer no longer exists after removing them)
  - Sure, I can remote in and add/remove them, but the GPO is what gave them access to the whitelisted remote support program. I can fix that in the future by imaging the computers w/ the proper rules, but that doesn't help w/ the 300 or so computers deployed before I was hired :#
- Tangential advice is totally welcome. As I said, I started off just taking tickets and repairing equipment, but now I'm also managing GPOs and rolling out applications, and learning it all from scratch informally. So if you have *any* direction in which to point me to resolve this, I'm all ears.

Here's the code I'm using, if it helps. Maybe I'm just missing something stupid obvious.

```
[Setup]
AppId={{3FE0499F-EE2B-42D7-8D3A-12D4A0DE802A}
AppName=IT Support GP Edit Tester
AppVersion=0.1
;AppVerName=IT Support GP Edit Tester 0.1
DefaultDirName=C:\Windows\System32\C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy
DefaultGroupName=IT Support GP Edit Tester
OutputDir=C:\Users\samwi\Desktop\Test Installers
OutputBaseFilename=CC IT GP Setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\samwi\Desktop\GroupPolicy\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: 
ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Comment: I do not see any description of the problem you have with your code. -- Though obviously `C:\Windows\System32\C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy` is an invalid path. -- Even if you use the correct path (and use `{sys}` constant, instead of hard-coding `C:\Windows\System32`), you may also have this problem: [File/DLL installed to {sys} does not appear in C:\Windows\system32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38270942/850848).