# Inno Setup is unable to install to LocalSystem's %LOCALAPPDATA%

Tags: inno-setup, local-system-account, localsystem

I have a Windows service that runs as the local system account. It stores some data in its `%LOCALAPPDATA%` folder. For `LocalSystem`, this is the following location:

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local
```

This works without a hitch; the service creates its own subfolder and writes files to it.

Now, using Inno Setup, I'm trying to install an initial file to that folder:

```
[Files]
Source: "LICENSE"; DestDir: "{sys}\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\InnoTest"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

The log suggests that this works fine:

```ini
[14:20:10,722]   -- File entry --
[14:20:10,725]   Dest filename: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\InnoTest\LICENSE
[14:20:10,729]   Time stamp of our file: 2022-10-24 13:56:42.000
[14:20:10,731]   Installing the file.
[14:20:10,734]   Creating directory: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\InnoTest
[14:20:10,738]   Successfully installed the file.
```

It says "successfully installed the file", **but neither the file nor the directory is anywhere to be seen**.

Run the installer again, however, and you will be told that the destination file exists:

```ini
[14:24:47,381]   -- File entry --
[14:24:47,395]   Dest filename: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\InnoTest\LICENSE
[14:24:47,398]   Time stamp of our file: 2022-10-24 13:56:42.000
[14:24:47,400]   Dest file exists.
[14:24:47,403]   Time stamp of existing file: 2022-10-24 13:56:42.000
[14:24:47,405]   Installing the file.
[14:24:47,410]   Successfully installed the file.
```

So: The installer thinks the file exists, but I can't see it.

This is specifically an issue with the System account; if I switch to, say, the `%LOCALAPPDATA%` of the `LocalService` account, things work as expected:

```
[Files]
Source: "LICENSE"; DestDir: "{win}\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\InnoTest"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

If anyone could shed some light on what is (or isn't) going on here, it would be much appreciated.

[Minimal, reproducible and complete example here](https://github.com/petterh/inno-test).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost a duplicate of:
[File/DLL installed to {sys} does not appear in C:\Windows\system32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38270942/850848)
Though your question probably deserves specific answer.

If I understand correctly, you want to install to `System32` on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems. So there are two options:

- Use the [64-bit mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls);
- If you do not want (or not dare) to switch whole installer to 64-bit mode, you will need two entries in the `[Files]` section. One for 64-bit systems with [`64bit` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=64bit) and one for 32-bit systems without the flag:

  ```
  [Files]
  Source: "LICENSE"; \
      DestDir: "{sys}\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\InnoTest"; \
      Flags: ignoreversion; Flags: 64bit; Check: IsWin64
  Source: "LICENSE"; \
      DestDir: "{sys}\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\InnoTest"; \
      Flags: ignoreversion; Check: not IsWin64
  ```